# How to change boot options on Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, usb, multi-boot

I am attending a robotics camp in a week and was given a USB and was told to set up my computer by booting it through the USB so that I can use Linux. I did this, and it worked successfully. But the camp isn't until next week and I want my normal Windows computer back. When I try to change the boot in Linux through the restart screen it doesn't give me an option to return to my original one, it only asks questions about whether I want my USB to be "active" and such. How do I return to my original operating system from Linux? Is it as simple as removing the USB?

I'm on an Acer laptop with Windows 10, trying to escape Linux.

Comment: We don't know what you did, so we don't know what you should revert (if anything). But removing the USB is obviously the first thing to try...

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it is going through the Linux booting screen at the restart, pressing escape, and then typing 'reboot.' It took me back to Windows. To go back to Linux, I just restart my computer again and go through the basic booting route. I'm not sure if this is the best or correct way to solve this, but it's the way I did and it's fairly simple.